# the office cubicles need to be replaced?

Tags: vocabulary

Does it make sense to say "the office cubicles need to be replaced" in the sense that the partitions need to be replaced?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not just say "The partitions need to be replaced."? Any answer depends on definitions you have not provided.

Comment: I'm asking this because an Australian coworker of mine wrote that. However, most, if not all, dictionaries say "cubicle" refers to the area or workspace enclosed by particians, That raises the question of whether my coworker used it incorrectly, or the definitions are inaccurate.

Comment: Are you a native speaker?

Comment: Yes, but AmE. To me, "cubicles" include the partitions and all fixtures within them. If you can't clear this up with definitions, then it either isn't a language question, or is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a miscommunication over the meaning of "cubicle", and not based on an English language error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. An "**office cubicle**" forms a partition that separates neighboring workspaces.

Comment: Is it natural to say "the office cubicle should be replaced" when we actually mean the partition WALLS need to be replaced? When saying "paritions," I do not mean the space, but the partition walls.

Comment: Is there some part of the cubicle that would otherwise be left behind or unnecessarily replaced? If the cubicle consists of the walls, it's okay to use them interchangeably here. Note that the contents (desk, person...) don't matter.

Comment: By saying "**office cubicle**" we may refer to the walls, to the workspace.